# Nested/Chained Resources in Rest

Tags: rest

This is a more of an architectural question. And I am rather new two Rest.

Let's assume these resources `/offers` and `/offers/:id`.
And the offer does have a single connection to an organization.
My first thought was creating a resource: `/offers/:id/organization`
This would be singular, because it feels unnatural to call the resource in plural, when there is always only one element returned.

**First question**: Would you always use plural no matter what?

This `/offers/:id/organization/:id` seems to be useless, because there is only one organization linked to the offer.

To make things complicated. The organizations need to be a separate resource as well: `/organizations` and `/organizations/:id`.

So basically I have to ways to achieve my goal.
I could get the `/offers`. And then with the retrieved organizationId get `/organization/:id`. Or I could nest the organization into the offer that I get everything in one request either `/offers` or `/offers/:id`.

The second option would potentially get rid of `/offers/:id/organization(s)`.
Except I wanted to get the organization by the offerId and not be the organizationId. (One organization has cn offers).

**Second question**: When there is a standalone resource, i.e `/organization`, should I bother of implementing a nested resource as well `/offer/:id/organization(s)`.

There is also the issue of how to implement the services (i am using jersey) if the organization is available at `/offers/:id/organization(s)` but that is probably a Question on its own.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [REST APIs must be hypertext-driven. I am getting frustrated by the number of people calling any HTTP-based interface a REST API.](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) — Roy Fielding, inventor of `REST`.

Comment: @AjAX. I probably do not know the exact meaning for hypertext-driven. And personally I do not care If I have a REST API or an HTTP based API. I am simply unsure how I should design my resources, whether it is RESTful or not.

Comment: 1: Singular. 2: No. 3: KISS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usually, it depends.

If your `offer` has only a single `organization`

```
/offers/:id/organization
```

is fine, because that is how your domain-model works.

This is different at

```
/organizations/:id/offers/:id
```

because, so I suspect, an `organization` could have multiple `offers`. So the `id` makes sense, also the resource `/organizations/:id/offers`, what are all offers for this `organization`.

You could implement

```
/offers/organization/:id
```

what could redirect to `/organizations/:id/offers` because it is semantically the same.

Comment: This seems to be a solid solution and helped sorting my thoughts. Thank you!